# Expressjs routes with graphql-yoga

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I am trying to build a  simple `api` at my backend using `graphql-yoga`. I have two files: `index.js` where the route file is called and graphql-yoga is initialized and the server running; and the second file, `routes.js` where all other routes  of the API are being defined to be used.
When accessing any non graphql url in the browser with a valid api key, eg: `mylocalhost.tld/anything?api_key=randomValues` , i am able able to access the resources without any error feedback. But when accessing a graphql route eg: `mylocalhost.tld/graphql?api_key=randomValues` i get a `Not Found` feedback.
When i comment out `routes(app);` in `index.js` and access `mylocalhost.tld/graphql/(*)` where (*) can be the playground , i am able to access graphql resources.

So what i need help with is to be able to access `mylocalhost.tld/graphql/(*)` without receiving a 404 error feedback.

**index.js**

```
     /**
     * index.js
     */

    // graphql
    import { GraphQLServer } from 'graphql-yoga';
    import graphql from '../graphql/schema';

    // other imports
    import routes from './routes';
    import os from 'os';


    // host
    const host = "http://" + (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? os.hostname() : "localhost");
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3060;


    // options
    const opts = {
        endpoint: '/graphql',
        port: port,
        tracing: true,
        playground: '/graphql/playground',
        cors: {
        origin: [host + ":3000"] // your frontend url.
      },
    }

    // context
    const context = (req) => ({
      req: req,
    });

    // server
    const server = new GraphQLServer({
        schema: graphql,
        // Align with behavior from express-graphql
        context: context,
    });

    // express
    const app = server.express;

    //Routes "./routes.js"
    routes(app);



    /**
     * Start server
     */
    server.start(opts, () => console.log(
        'Server listening at %s:%s in %s environment. \n',
        host,
        port,
        app.set('env'),
        ),
    );

    export default app;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------ //
```

**routes.js**

```
    /**
     * routes.js
     */

    import authApi from '../lib/api';


    export default (app) => {



      app.use('*', authApi); // this lets all routes request for a valid api key before delivering resources

      /**
       * Extract GraphQL API Key
       */
      app.use('/graphql/:api_key?', (req, res, next) => {
        req.api_key = req.params.api_key;
        next();
      });

    }; // end of app
```